# How do I associate a field value with another value of a multi-value field?

Tags: 7, entities

I've run into a situation with a project in regards to field organization. I've got 3 data types, a `price`, a `date range` and a `quantity`. I've currently got 4 prices and a date grouped with it using field groups. Quantities are a multivalue check list with values between 1-12. I have since learned that there is to be a different price for every quantity, so I would end up with up to four price and dates for each value of quantity I have.

So what I would like to know is the best way to go about this. Is there a way to set fields so that I when I can set an association between a group of dates & prices with a value of quantity or do I need to go for some kind of table-based approach?

Currently it is set up like this:

```
Node {
    price1
    date1
    price2
    date2
    price3
    date3
    price4
    date4
    quantity: 4, 7, 9, etc.
}
```

and I need to re-organize it like this:

```
Quantity: 4 { price1, date1, price2, date2…}
Quantity: 7 { price1, date1, price2, date2, price3, date3…}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found what may be a possible solution using the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.